# Add custom keywords in EXIF of .jpg files

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, photo, exif

I'm trying to add custom EXIF in .jpg files in a folder. I don't have errors but when I try to open the EXIF manually I don't see my adds.

The first block is the window and the second is the add to the EXIF.

def ajout_motcle():
global fenetre_custom, motcle_entry
fenetre_custom = Tk()
fenetre_custom.geometry('600x600')
fenetre_custom.title('Custom TAGS')
fenetre_custom.configure(bg='white')
fenetre_custom.resizable(height=False, width=False)
motcle = tk.StringVar()
motcle_entry = (Entry(fenetre_custom, textvariable=motcle, width='80'))
motcle_entry.place(x='50', y='200')
motcle_label = tk.Label(fenetre_custom, text='Add your keywords here, seperate by a coma', font=('avenir', 14, "bold"))
motcle_label.place(x='50', y='50')
valider_bouton = Button(fenetre_custom, text="Valider", command=ajout_exif)
valider_bouton.place(x=450, y=450)
fenetre_custom.mainloop()

def ajout_exif():
global source
motcle = motcle_entry.get()
liste_motcle = motcle.split(",")
fichiers = os.listdir(source)

```
for image_filename in fichiers:
    chemin_image = os.path.join(source, image_filename)

    try:
        image = Image.open(chemin_image)

        exif_data = image._getexif()

        if exif_data is not None:
            exif_data[TAGS.get("Keywords")] = ','.join(liste_motcle)
            image.save(chemin_image)
            print(exif_data)

            image.close()
    except (OSError, PIL.UnidentifiedImageError) as e:
        print(f"Erreur lors du traitement de {chemin_image}: {e}")
```

I'm trying to add custom keywords in EXIF of .jpg files in a Folder